# MBP security and safety

Tags: macos, security

At work, I rely on a public wifi and don't see any good security standards or requirements or tips from Apple. Are there some general tips on first steps to take for securing OS X - if so they would be of great help to me in learning how to secure my Mac.

Whats the best way to keep my late 2012 MBP safe and secure?

Comment: Best is to turn off all radios and disconnect from Ethernet. Might you want to narrow down your criteria or perhaps explain what risk you wish to mitigate? This might get closed as too broad without some more refinement.

Comment: @bmike Thank you for the suggestion. I use a public wifi at work daily. So i want to make sure that my personal info is safe as possible. I am always careful to avoid banking sites obviously. Just looking for what to avoid and how to set up my MBP.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the firewall (System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Firewall). Also click on the Advanced settings, and enable "stealth mode".  This will help a bit with protecting you on public WiFi networks by not acknowledging ping packets and similar.

Don't enable any Sharing options (System Preferences > Sharing) unless you're positive you need them. Things like Remote Login and File Sharing are especially dangerous if your passwords are insecure.

Be wary in general of things you see. If there's a page (fake) that states you have hundreds of viruses that need to be removed, don't believe it. Think before you act basically. Easier said than done, but it's really the best summary of best practices.

So many people also forget about the fact that your bank or other important institutions will NEVER ask for personal information via email or for you to "update settings". When in doubt, go directly to the relevant institution's site.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using HTTPS in your browser.

Turn of Sharing

Turn On Firewall

Newer use sensitive connections like your bank on a public network.

Here is one often overlooked:

Make sure you actually connect to Starbucks wifi while at their store and not connected to a fake wifi server pretending to be Starbuck.

Basically means knowing who is the provider of the public wifi.

Make sure no one is looking over your shoulder seen what you typing as a user and passwords.

Comment: Okay this is of good help for me. ALways good to check the wifi provider, thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome, stay safe. Monitor your accounts for suspicious activity.

Comment: Actually I do use banking on public wifi, but I mask my transactions using simultaneous (open other tabs in browser) upload and download and watching some video, so lots of traffic on my WiFi, makes it externally difficult for a "sniffer" to distinguish what is what. I know it is not the holy grail but to be hones the hackers hacked even those.

Answer (score -1):

Use a VPN to thwart Man in the middle